# How to save a mongodb collection as array of documents

Tags: javascript, mongodb

So, the problem is that I want to obtain data from a mongoDB collection to use it later in another piece of code. Are there any ways to obtain data from all documents in collection to work with them in javascript, without mongoDB library?

For now, I have some code:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var assert = require('assert');
var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/website';

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {    
    assert.equal(null, err);
    console.log("Connected correctly to server.");
    findGoods(db, function() {
    db.close();
    });
});

var findGoods = function(db, callback) {
    var cursor = db.collection('goodsList').find( );
};
```

Comment: What do you mean by "without mongoDB library"? How else would you get your data unless calling some external service?

Comment: Sorry, I meant that I wanted to export result in another file and use data without any libraries if possible. Actually, it is not a problem to use external library or use only one, I just wanted to keep it simpler.

Comment: Have you thought about exporting the API calls (your `findGoods` function, in this case) instead?

Comment: Well, I don't really know how to do this... I'm just not experienced. And not smart.

Comment: We'll have none of that kind of talk here! Have you read the Meteor Guide? Specifically the section on [importing/exporting](https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html#intro-to-import-export)?

Comment: I'm very sorry, but exporting is not main problem. I just want to retrieve data from all documents in collection.

Answer (score 0):

So, I found answer, to my question. I asked my friend about it, so if anybody needs code, here is it:

```
var findGoods = function(db, callback) {
    var collection = db.collection('goodsList');
    collection.find({}).toArray( function(err, docs) {
        if (!err) {
            console.log(docs)
        } else {
            console.error(err)
        }
    })
};
```